# What is the difference between the ADD and COPY Dockerfile instructions?

Tags: docker, copy, addition

A - ADD supports remote URL handing while COPY does not might be 
 B - ADD supports regular expression handling while COPY does not
 C - ADD supports compression format handling while COPY does not
 D - COPY supports regular expression handling while ADD does not

I appreciate you help guys

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the [Dockerfile reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) website, you can see that COPY and ADD obey different rules.  If you have certain needs, you can pick one over the other.  For most rules COPY is fine, but I would suggest too look at the reference to pick the best option for your needs.